# Checking if value from list is an integer

Tags: types, int, python-3.6

I'm trying to make a hexadecimal to decimal calculator and i'm trying to check if the input has integer or character.

How can I accomplish this?

```
def hex2dec(value):
    dict = {'A':10,'B':11,'C':12,'D':13,'E':14,'F':15}
    strVal = str(value)
    length = len(strVal)
    decimal = 0
    for i in range(0,length):
        try:
            int(strval[i:i+1])
            val = "int"
        except ValueError:
            val = "not int"

    return val

value = int(input("Enter Hexadecimal Value: "),16)
print("Value in Hexadecimal : ", hex2dec(value))
```

Whenever I run the codes and input any single digit or alphabet from A to F it returns `int`.

Anyone knows the solution to this?

Comment: Just for fun (no answer): try `print("Value in Decimal : ", value)`. (Assuming the prompt is wrong, of course.)

Comment: @usr2564301 yes but i do not want to use the in built function to convert, i'm trying to make my own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always get `"int"` because the function is always *called* with an `int`. The variable `value` gets converted to an integer because of `int(..)` in the `input` line.

If you want to check first, feed the original *string* input into your function:

```
value = input("Enter Hexadecimal Value: ")
```

You don't need to check one character at a time, this will work as well:

```
try:
    int(strVal)
    val = "int"
except ValueError:
    val = "not int"
```

Note that there is no good reason to check in your function! Even if you *seemingly* enter an integer -- `123` --, you must still process this as a hexadecimal number. Checking if it's also an integer has no use at that point.

Comment: Yupp it works, thanks for pointing out my mistake for casting my input as int

Answer (score 1):

With this line

```
value = int(input("Enter Hexadecimal Value: "),16)
```

you have already converted the provided value to an integer.

If you want to perform the conversion yourself, first accept what they have entered as a string (remove the use of `int()` in the above statement).

Also note that a submission of `"12"` is a valid hexadecimal value, with a decimal value of `18`.

Comment: ah yes my bad when i was searching for my previous problems, i encountered a post mentioning to put the base 16 in the input to allow hexadecimal values onto int casting.

Answer (score 0):

Extending the previous answer, you could do:

```
if (strval[i:i+1] in dict.keys()) or (type(strval[i:i+1]) == int):
    val = 'int'
else
    'val = 'not int'
```

in order to check if the value is an `int` or in your dict (additionally you get some   extensibility..)